# Vue.js detach styles from template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use a template with a `<style>` block which **must be near its div** for CMS reasons.

When I run Vue.js, it seems to remove the style block, saying...

```
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI.     
  Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, 
  as they will not be parsed.
```

What can I do?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <style>
    #div_123 {
      background: http://placehold.it/850x150;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      #div_123 {
         background: http://placehold.it/350x150;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div id="div_123">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give the reasons as to why it has to be so close to the div?

Comment: I use dynamic background images which are bound to my div and I can't place them for CMS reason somewhere else than here...

Comment: Is the style going to be associated with a component or just a Vue?

Comment: @BertEvans juste to a view. It has to stay in HTML because it's generated server-side

Comment: Can you explain why you felt the accepted answer was a valid solution to your question? That is, you have a `<style>` block that "must be near its div", but the solution instead moves styling to jQuery (which requires another lib, natch) and a call to VueJS' `mount`. Did you find an answer closer to your original query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for my specific situation where I allow the users to store a string of CSS and then I need to render it on specific pages - ei: preview page.

The context here is `css`  is saved as string in database, fetched and rendered within an Vue component.

```
# html
<html>
  <head>
    <style id="app_style"></style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
# app.vue

data() {
  return {
    dynamic_css: ''
  }
},

created() {
  // fetch css from database, set as `this.dynamic_css`
},

watch {
  dynamic_css: function(newValue) {
    document.getElementById('app_style').innerHTML = newValue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### The Issue

In Vue 2 the root instance is treated more like a component than it was in Vue 1.

This means when you bind the Vue instance to #app it digests everything in #app as a vue template.  This means  tags are invalid and they'll be removed from the template.  This is just the way things work in Vue 2.

### Recreation

I recreated the issue in a codepen here

https://codepen.io/Fusty/pen/gqXavm?editors=1010

The `<style>` tag nested within the tag Vue is bound to.  It should style the background red and the text color green.  However, we see only a flash of this (depending on how fast your browser fires up Vue) and eventually vue removes these style tags as it digest #app as a template and then updates the DOM with what it thinks should be there (without `<style>` tags).

### Better Recreation

Thanks to user @joestrouth1#6053 on the Vue-Land discord, we also have this fork of my recreation of the issue.

https://codepen.io/joestrouth1/pen/WPXrbg?editors=1011

Check out the console.  It reads . . .

```
"[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.

1  |  <div>
2  |      <style>
   |      ^^^^^^^
... etc ...
```

Complaining about the style tags in a template.

This zeroes in on the actual issue.  It is good to note this doesn't occur in Vue 1.  Probably because it treats the root instance more uniquely than components, but I am not 100% sure on this topic.

### Solution (Hack, not best practice or especially recommended)

The `<style>` tags are still in the DOM during the `created` lifecycle hook for the Vue instance and they are removed by the time the `mounted`lifecycle hook fires.  Let's just query for all of the style tags within the #app element, save them, and then append them back to the #app element after Vue has digested the template.

Adding the following to your root Vue instance will take any `<style>` tags within whatever element your Vue instance is bound to (via `el: 'someSelector'`) and append them (possibly relocating them) to the element your Vue instance is bound to.

```
  created: function() {
    this.styleTagNodeList = document.querySelector(this.$options.el).querySelectorAll('style');
  },
  mounted: function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.styleTagNodeList.length; ++i)
      this.$el.appendChild(this.styleTagNodeList[i]);
  }
```

NOTE:  This is definitely a hack which likely has unintended consequences I have not run into yet and cannot specifically disclaim.  USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.